# customize-cra, (react-app-rewired) how to override paths

Tags: reactjs

I'm using https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#readme and my config-overrides.js looks like

```
 module.exports = override(
...
)
```

Now the doc says you can override paths with this form

```
module.exports = {

  paths: function(paths, env) {
    // ...add your paths config
    return paths;
  },
}
```

How do I combine the two where the first one uses `override` function and second one uses object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `paths`, set it in the object.
For other overrides, use `webpack` keyword (if you are intending to override webpack configurations).
So, bellow is from one of my repos (where I have all the client source codes under `client` directory):

```js
const path = require('path');
const { override, addBabelPresets } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = {
  paths: (paths, env) => {
    paths.appIndexJs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/index.jsx');
    paths.appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client');
    return paths;
  },
  webpack: override(
    addBabelPresets(
      '@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop'
    )
  ),
}
```